# Protecting Base class object in C#

Tags: c#

How

```
 public class BaseAppConstants
    {
        public const string StLiveIdCookieName = "XYZ";
    }


public class AppConstants : BaseAppConstants
{


}
```

How can I make changes so user can not direct access base class they can only use like this  `AppConstants.StLiveIdCookieName;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should either

- A) move the constant to the level at which is it supposed to be used (i.e. declare it in `AppConstants` and remove it from `BaseAppConstants`) or,
- B) use a different modifier to make it inaccessible and provide an accessor in the other class (i.e. use `protected` in `BaseAppConstants` and reimplement in `AppConstants` with something like `public const string StLiveIdCookieName = BaseAppConstants.StLiveIdCookieName` - but this kind of defies the usage of constants).

Answer (score 1):

If you set the property in the base class to protected it will only be usable in derived classes.

```
public class BaseAppConstants
{
    protected const string StLiveIdCookieName = "XYZ";
}
```

Read more about protected [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

use protected modifier
seee :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7(v=vs.71).aspx

and for deteiled explanation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2(v=vs.71).aspx